# Installing USB driver for Nexus 4 (with KitKat) on Windows 8 64-bit - "no compatible software driver"

Tags: android, windows-8, windows-8.1, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-4

I'm desperately trying to install ADB USB drivers for my Nexus 4, which (as you might know) are required for any form of Android Development. You could also say, that they are the single most necessary tool used for Android programming, right? I have already often set up an Android Development Environment for my old HTC Desire, but I am failing with setting it up for my Nexus 4.

The way I go about it:

- Running Windows 8 and 8.1 Preview (tried everything on two different machines)
- Downloading the Android Development Tools from Google (SDK+ADT+Eclipse+etc.)
- Downloading the Google USB Drivers (v8) via Android SDK Manager
- In the Device Manager i have an entry "Nexus 4" which I right-click and then I select "Update Driver Software..."
- -> Browse my Computer for driver software -> Let me pick a list of device drivers on my computer -> Have Disk... -> Choose Path to          Google Drivers -> Dialog occurs:
- "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. [...]"

I really do not know what the problem is. Some things I already tried include:

- Doing everything on USB3/USB2 Port
- Changing Computer Connection Mode to PTP (instead of MTP)
- Doing everything on Win8/Win8.1 Preview
- I tried to install the universal ADB Driver: download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi without any significant result

I fear that the problem is because of the new driver version (v8) or KitKat, because I can't find any working solutions on the net and KitKat is relatively new, however, does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your qquestion does not contain anything with is related to programming so http://superuser.com it the better choise for your question.

Comment: Hmm... i can access my files and have a driver for the device, but the driver I'm talking about in my question is a special driver needed for Android App Development. I thought that would be enough related to programming. Is it not?

Comment: Maybe I'm no moderator so it's just my opinion. I think this is a problem about installing a driver, and this is more suitable for superuser.

Comment: You should post this answer in Stack Exchange's Android Enthusiast.

Anyway, try to install the universal ADB Driver: http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I tried to install the universal driver and now the device is listed as "Google Nexus ADB Interface", but besides my Nexus 4 storage not beeing displayed in the explorer there are no changes. By the way "adb devices" delivers an empty list as well.

Should I post the question at Android Enthusiast now? Will no one complain about double posting or something similiar?

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem: Enable Debug-Mode on the device! Before you do anything in order to develop on a Nexus 4 (at least in my experience), do the following: - Settings App->About Phone->click 7x "Build number" to active the Developer Mode - Settings main screen->Developer options->enable "USB debugging" In my defense: It doesn't say anywhere, that this is a prequisite for Android development. I knew of this option, but since the last time I set this option on a device is years ago, I just thought to myself "well... I do not want to debug, so this option is irrelevant"

Comment: @AndrewBarber This is *not* a general computing question as the question states, because it is necessary for every Android developer to use ADB if they want to test their app.

Comment: @Wolf If you find the answer to your question, you can answer your own question. Wait until it gets reopened, then click the Answer your Own Question button at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Debug-Mode on the device.

**Steps to enable debug mode:**

Before you do anything in order to develop on a Nexus 4 (at least in my experience), do the following:

- Open **Settings** App
- Navigate to **About Phone**
- click **Build number** seven times  to active the Developer Mode - Settings main screen->Developer options->enable "USB debugging"

In my defense: It doesn't say anywhere, that this is a prequisite for Android development. I knew of this option, but since the last time I set this option on a device is years ago, I just thought to myself "well... I do not want to debug, so this option is irrelevant"

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all - sorry for my English.

If you have a Windows 7 - just update your Windows Media Player.
If you install Google USB Driver - remove it before updating WMP!

Comment: A bit more explanation of why this solves the problem, or what causes the problem would improve your answer.

Comment: I don't know - why, But I have a Windows 7N (this topic is for Win8). It goes without a WMP. I'm tried to install Android Studio, use a USB ADB driver - nothing helped. Then I remembered, that I have similar problem with PC rating (it doesn't work without Windows Media Player). I'm installed it and phone started to work as a Flash-drive.